# gnuplot: Histogram Required with stacked bars

Tags: gnuplot

[Output Should be something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p3vdZ.jpg)

can anyone please help me with a sample code to build histogram for below data. I am very new to this and would really appreciate some help.

```
Date_Stat   Total   Success Gen_decline Failure_incomplete
01.05.2018  42045   39164   2096    785   
02.05.2018  33721   30857   1727    1137
03.05.2018  28159   26042   1513    604
```

Comment: I updated the indenting...and you just removed it. What would your histogram be?

Comment: I want the dates on x axis and values on Y axis

Comment: So the histogram is done, you just want a plot style?

Comment: Something from here? http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo/histograms.html

Comment: Hi Matt, appreciate your help here. I am very new to this, I wanted to create a graph for the data mentioned above. I came across gnuplot while searching online and hope this can be achieved by gnuplot.
yes the second graph in your link should serve my purpose.

Comment: I updated question with the image what I am expecting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't look to good, but it is a start. First I saved the data into a file "so-dat.txt" pretty much as shown. Then I used this gnuplot script.

```
set boxwidth 0.9 absolute
set style fill   solid 1.00 border lt -1
set key right top vertical Right noreverse noenhanced autotitle nobox
set style histogram clustered gap 1 title textcolor lt -1
set datafile missing '-'
set style data histograms
set xtics border in scale 0,0 nomirror rotate by -45  autojustify
set xtics  norangelimit 
set xtics   ()
set title "data" 
set yrange [ 0.00000 : 45000. ] noreverse nowriteback
## Last datafile plotted: "immigration.dat"
plot 'so-dat.txt' using 2:xtic(1) ti col, '' u 3 ti col, '' u 4 ti col, '' u 5 ti col
```

That creates a bar chart with 3 clusters (by date) of four columns (Total Success Gen_decline failure_incomplete.)

To make the key horizontal.

```
set key right horizontal noenhanced autotitle nobox
```

Or even set the key above. Although that is above the title.

```
set key above horizontal autotitle nobox
```

Comment: Many Thanks, worked fine for my data. Can we move labels {Success, Total etc.} in a horizontal line on top

Comment: @AbhishekVarshney yes, change the command from vertical to horizontal. Then also make sure the gaph has enough room.

Comment: Great @matt , will try them out. Will vote for your answer, thanks again.